# Название ячейки массива

Tags: c#

Как можно назвать ячейку массива не числом, а буквами?

```
string[] foods = new string[1024];
foods["pizza"] = 1;
foods["bread"] = 4;
```

Comment: `Dictionary<string, int>` [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: никак - в массиве допустимы только числовые индексы

Answer (score 1):

Чисто теоретически, можно создать класс, перезагрузить оператор скобочек... Но зачем это делать если есть что то готовое? `Dictionary<string, int>` вам отлично подойдёт!
Пример:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ExampleNamepace;
{
    public class ExampleProgram
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var foods = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            foods.Add("pizza", 1);
            foods.Add("bread", 4);
            foods["pizza"] = foods["bread"] + 1;

            Console.WriteLine(foods["pizza"]); // food["pizza"] = 5
        }
    }
}
```

- [Dictionary](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)